# backColor of Combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

when my combox style is DropDownList then setting the BackColor works only on that drop down list that we open by clicking on the combobox but it does Not affect the text area of the combobox where we have not yet clicked the combobox to open its list... how can I do that to get the same back color for the text area too ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can, at least not programmatically through the ComboBox's properties. That other color you're seeing when the ComboBox isn't expanded is the item selection rectangle. That is configurable through Windows' color scheme settings, although it isn't practical to change a system-wide setting just so you can get these colors to match.